# npm install is not working on botkit starter facebook project

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install, botkit

I would like to develop a chatbot and then chose botkit as the tool to use. Following the steps to install it as described [here](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-facebook),I first cloned the repository to my local disk D: this worked but the second step command (for Installing dependencies, including Botkit:)

```
cd botkit-starter-facebook
npm install
```

doesn't work giving me the error :[image: screenshot of the error]

I don't understand what that means so it is hard for me to solve it. 
I am using windows 7 x64bits pack 1 and `node version 6.9.5` and `npm version 3.10.10`

Git was not in the path system environment variable and I add it but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because git is not installed or not in the path. npm is trying to pull some dependency from github but unable to clone it as git is not available. Once you have git working, this should work.

Comment: What do you mean but git is not installed, I cloned the repository using git, I am a little bit confused I have git on my computer.

Comment: @aidonsnous Please check if git is in your path, this is definitely a problem with your git installation and not with npm or botkit

Comment: windows can do that sometime to you :P

Comment: it was not in the path system environment variable and I add it but I am still getting the same error

Comment: The problem which made the path I added to not work was the git application was not in the main folder C:\Program Files\Git but in C:\Program Files\Git\cmd